# Can you retrieve messages in a Storage Queue that are created with visibilityTimeout

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm creating messages in an Azure Storage Queue, using the visibilityTimeout option. They appear nicely in the queue when the timeout passed. Great!

Now imagine a message was created using the wrong visibilityTimeout value (e.g. too far ahead in the future). Is it possible to retrieve that message from the queue, so it can be updated and/or deleted?

FYI, I'm creating the message using the following snippet:

```js
queueSvc.createMessage('js-queue-items', queueMessageBuffer, { "visibilityTimeout": 10}, function (e, r) { ... });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now imagine a message was created using the wrong visibilityTimeout
>   value (e.g. too far ahead in the future). Is it possible to retrieve
>   that message from the queue, so it can be updated and/or deleted?

Unfortunately no. The message will remain invisible to all callers. It will become visible only after `visibilityTimeout` has elapsed.

Comment: Note: this is the case for both "get" and "peek." Also note that the maximum invisibility timeout is 7 days, so *eventually* these messages will show up and can be properly cleared out.